Choosing Gate Driver Topology and Isolation for a 5-Level Cascaded H-Bridge Inverter
I am designing a 5-level cascaded H-bridge inverter and need guidance on selecting the appropriate gate driver circuit topology. My main questions are:

Can I use a gate driver IC like the IRF2104S for each inverter leg as shown in circuit 1, or is it better to use individual isolated gate driver ICs (e.g., 1EDB7275F) for each MOSFET as in circuit 2?

Created in Altium
https://www.infineon.com/export/sites/default/_images/product/power/GateDriver/circuit_diagram/1ED38x0mu12.1.jpg_1080674195.jpg

Isolation Requirements: Is it necessary to isolate the gate driver power supply for each MOSFET from the inverter's input DC voltage? If so, what is the recommended approach to achieve this isolation?


Design Details:
Inverter output power 500W
The input DC voltage to the inverter is 160 V.
The switching frequency is 5000 Hz.
MOSFET: STF16N60M2
I would also appreciate any guidelines or best practices for hardware implementation of this inverter, specifically regarding the inverter design.

I'm curious, how will you get five different levels from this? How does it differ from a dual active bridge?

The 5-level CHB inverter consists of multiple H-bridge cells connected in series. Each H-bridge has its own DC source, and by controlling the switches, you can create different voltage levels. You can find more on https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/cascaded-h-bridge-inverter  It is used for DC - AC conversion.  Please let me know if you need any further clarifications.
